# Getting error when compressing PNG image - imagepng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: bad parameters to zlib

Tags: php

I am getting an error in php when I try to compress my png images. Here is my code:

```
public function compress() {
   $filePath = "/path/image.png";
   $image = @imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
   if (!$image) return;
   
   // compress with 60% of quality
   imagepng($image, $filePath, 60);
}
```

Here is the error message:

> imagepng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: bad parameters to zlib

I am getting this error when I execute "imagepng" function. Why I am getting this error? thank you

Comment: [imagepng()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng) requires a compression quality from 0 to 9, so 60 is way out of range.

Comment: Side-note: The param name "quality" is a bit misleading in the case of PNG. PNG uses lossless (zip) compression. The quality of the contents will always remain at 100% after compression (unlike in JPEG). A higher compression level just means that more time is used to better compress the file. EDIT: I just realized the same point was made in the user notes here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng#usernotes

Comment: Always read the documentation carefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quality parameter of the `imagepng()` function only takes values from 0 - 9.

- 0 = no compression
- 9 = max compression.

Which means the function can't use your input 60

Reference:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng says:

> quality: Compression level: from 0 (no compression) to 9. The default (-1) uses the zlib compression default. For more information see the » [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).